# Ortholines in GeoTools

Tags: geotools

I am using GeoTools 10.7 to generate a map with decorations in my Java application.
One of the feature I need in the map is to display ortholines both latitude and longitude. The lines will need to be updated when I zoom to maintain relatively constant gaps in pixels - for example, if the initial presentation shows lines are 10 degrees apart using 100 pixels.  When I zoom the map, 100 pixel gap should remain unchanged but update the lat or lon values.

There is an example at GeoTools web site ["Vector grids"](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/grid.html#grids-for-display-in-different-map-projections), and I followed the "Line grids" example thinking the major and minor lines are displayed one at a time depending on my zoom level.

My attempt so far:

```
ReferencedEnvelope currentBounds = getCurrentExtent();
ReferencedEnvelope gridBounds = new ReferencedEnvelope(
        currentBounds.getMinX(),
        currentBounds.getMaxX(),
        currentBounds.getMinY(),
        currentBounds.getMaxY(), landCRS);

// Line definitions 
lineDefs = Arrays.asList(
        new OrthoLineDef(LineOrientation.VERTICAL, 2, 5.0),
        new OrthoLineDef(LineOrientation.VERTICAL, 1, 1.0),
        new OrthoLineDef(LineOrientation.HORIZONTAL, 2, 5.0)
        new OrthoLineDef(LineOrientation.HORIZONTAL, 1, 1.0));

// Specify vertex spacing to get "densified" polygons
double vertexSpacing = 0.1;
OrthoLineFeatureBuilder olBuilder = new OrthoLineFeatureBuilder(OrthoLineFeatureBuilder.VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, CRS);
grid = Lines.createOrthoLines(gridBounds, lineDefs, vertexSpacing, olBuilder);

GeometryDescriptor geomDesc = grid.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor();
geometryAttributeName = geomDesc.getLocalName();

Rule rule = sf.createRule();

// Text symbolizer
Fill fill1 = sf.createFill(ff.literal(new Color(255,255,255,100)));
AnchorPoint anchorPoint = sf.createAnchorPoint(ff.literal(0.5d), ff.literal(0d));
LabelPlacement labelPlacement = sf.createPointPlacement(anchorPoint, null, ff.literal(0));
TextSymbolizer text = sf.createTextSymbolizer();
text.setFont(sf.createFont(ff.literal("Arial"), ff.literal(false), ff.literal(false), ff.literal(10)));
text.setLabel(ff.property(OrthoLineFeatureBuilder.VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME));
text.setFill(fill1);
text.setLabelPlacement(labelPlacement);
rule.symbolizers().add(text);

Rule rules[] = {rule, createRule(GeomType.LINE, new Color(255, 255, 255, 100), null)};
FeatureTypeStyle fts = sf.createFeatureTypeStyle(rules);
Style style = sf.createStyle();
style.featureTypeStyles().add(fts);

gridsLayer = new FeatureLayer(grid, style);
```

With this code, I only get the lines displayed at every 1 degree in both direction, and remains at 1 degree separation at any zoom level.  So when I zoom in, lines become far apart, and when I zoom out they get closer (obviously!)

---

Solved (hack or not) using DirectLayer.